# Retrieving data in XML in a specific format by using an SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

[Click here for the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1JlQ.png).

I need any type of script to retrieve the XML format data by using an SQL Server query in the following specific format.

Here is the script for the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE school
(
    class int,
    section varchar(1),
    studentName varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO school (class, [section], studentName)
VALUES (1, 'A', 'Mahesh'),
       (1, 'A', 'Jack'),
       (1, 'A', 'Kismo'),
       (1, 'B', 'Hari'),
       (1, 'B', 'Khan');
```

```xml
<listResponse Section="A" count= "3" >
    <instance class="1" studentName="Mahesh"/>
    <instance class="1" studentName="Jack"/>
    <instance class="1" studentName="Kismo"/>
</listResponse>
```

I'm looking for a query to retrieve the data in the exact, shown XML format. The example table or data can be anything.

Comment: What is your question here? Are you looking to create that XML or consume it? It almost reads like you want to consume that XML to create that XML, which is a fruitless endeavour. Sample data (in a *consumable* format, **not** an image), and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: I want script to retrieve data in the prescribed xml format @Larnu

Comment: You additionally need to explain some of the logic used to generate the XML. e.g.: There are five rows with class 1, so why are only 3 shown in the XML? Where do `type="Section"` and `count="3"` come from? What T-SQL code have you tried so far and why isn't it working for you?

Comment: select 
section as [@section],
count(section) as [@count],
Max(studentName) as [Instance/@studentName],
Min(class) as [Instance/@class]
from school  
group by section
for XML PATH('TypeResponse'),ROOT('School');
select * from school;

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to use a nested query here. I filter to `section` `'A'` in the outer query, and then correlate the query here:

```sql
SELECT Section AS [@type],
       COUNT(*) [@count],
       (SELECT class as [@class],
               studentName AS [@studentName]
        FROM dbo.school sN
        WHERE sN.section = s.section
        FOR XML PATH('instance'),TYPE)
FROM dbo.school s
WHERE s.section = 'A'
GROUP BY s.section
FOR XML PATH('listResponse');
```

Comment: In the first line of the xml code, i want like this "<listResponse Section="A" count= "3" >"

Comment: Had `Section` in single quotes, fixed. Please learn to actually *explain* the issue, cryptic non-explanative comments aren't helpful. YOu should have said something like *"The XML has `"Section="Section"` not `Section="A"`."*